# error on storm nimbus daemon

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, apache-storm, nimbus

i'm trying to run apache storm on my ubuntu. for this i should run nimbus daemon. the problem is when i type the command storm nimbus
, it gives me an error:

> ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath:
>   /usr/lib/storm/cluster.xml
>
> ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for
>   'AsyncContext@2503dbd3' at 'null' in 'null'

i found the cluster.xml file from log4j directory and placed it on the storm directory and start nimbus, but this time it stopped without any error with an exception :

> expected '', but found BlockMappingStart

does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the old configuration of config file: storm/conf/storm.yaml
In version 1.1 of storm, instead of nimbus.host, use nimbus.seeds.